# How to use one variable in Program.cs and Api endpoint respectively a business component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, global-variables

I have a .NET web Api and inside my Program.cs a variable (a Dictionary) which is manipulated there. But I need to read this variable in my Api endpoint or the business class to the endpoint. What is a good way to make my variable visible on the Api endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Add a public static variable (Dictionary) to your Programm.cs.

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> MyData = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Use it at your controller class.

```
var SourceData = Program.MyData;
```

From there you can also pass it as argument to your business class.

```
result = BusinessComponent.GetResult(SourceData );
```

> Note: That's not threat save!